# Как реализовать запрет наложения draggable-элементов?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Добрый день!

Допустим, есть следующая разметка:

```
<div id="someId"
   <ul id="someList">
       <li>First item</li>
       <li>Second item</li>
       <li>Third item</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Ширина родительского дива намного больше ширины списка (реальность этого значения особого значения не имеет). Главное, что справа от списка осталось место для перетаскивания элементов `<li>`. Использую плагин `jQuery.draggable()`.

`$(function(){
   $(#someList li).draggable();
});`

Всё работает. Но для меня принципиально сохранить поведение аналогичного плагина `jQuery.sortable()`. Именно не сортировку, а именно поведение элементов. Если не понятно - при применении этого плагина сортируемые элементы занимают новое положение строго до или после (слева-справа) следующего элемента (в зависимости где закончилось перетаскивание элемента), то есть элементы не накладываются.

Никто не подскажет как реализовать подобное поведение для плагина `draggable()`? чтобы элементы не накладывались друг на друга, а занимали место рядом с элементом, через которого ведётся перетаскивание. Как определить, что перетаскиваемый элемент находится в данный момент над другим элементом?

PS я использовал `containment`. Все нужные элементы перемещаются в одной области, как надо, не выходят за границы родительского элемента. Всё работает!только элементы **накладываются** друг на друга. Мне надо как раз **отменить** это наложение. То есть добавить к draggable поведение sortable при наложении элементов. Я подозреваю, что это делается через `ui.position.left` и автоматическое обновления сведений о положении элементов по завершению перетаскивания. Понимаю, что положение перетаскиваемого элемента должно сравниваться с положением уже статичных элементов, если перекрытие - двигаем элемент. Но реализовать как-то не получается.

Comment: это что бан?второй мой вопрос остаётся вообще без внимания....

Comment: вопрос не простой, почему вы изначально не использовали `sortable`? `draggable` предназначен для свободного перемещения элементов без взаимодействия с другими элементами

Comment: @Spectre, конечно я использовал. в `sortable` мне как раз не хватает именно свободного  перемещения элементов....в общем, немного хочу объединить.

Answer (score 2):

А разве в описании draggable этого нету?

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#sortable

Насколько я понял Вам надо совместить [Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) и [Droppable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/) :

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $(".drag" ).draggable({containment:"#main_box", axis:"x"});

        $(".drop" ).droppable({hoverClass:"high",
                    accept:".drag",
            drop: function( event, ui ) 
            {
               var left1 = $(this).position().left;
               var left2 = ui.draggable.position().left;

               $(this).css("left",(left2 + (((left1>left2)?(+1):(-1))*ui.draggable.width()))+"px");
               //TODO: думаю имеет смыст переосмыслить позиции у всех элементов контейнера
            },

            over: function( event, ui)
            {
                $(this).css("left",ui.draggable.css("left"));
            }

        });
    });
</script>
...
<!-- Задаём контейнер так: -->
<div id="main_box" style="width:300px;height:30px;border: 1px solid;">
  <div class="drag drop" style="position:absolute;top:3px;left:0px;border:1px solid; background-color: red; width:20px;height:20px;">1</div>
  <div class="drag drop" style="position:absolute;top:3px;left:20px;border:1px solid; background-color: green; width:20px;height:20px;">2</div>
  <div class="drag drop" style="position:absolute;top:3px;left:40px;border:1px solid; background-color: blue; width:20px;height:20px;">3</div>
</div>
```

И, естественно, style лучше перенести в css.

А элементы тогда маркируйте двумя классами **class="draggable droppable"**

Да, и раз это читает [[@Spectre](/users/3159/spectre)](/users/3159/spectre) то оформите это в качестве [плагина](http://xdan.ru/Kak-napisat-plagin-na-jQuery.html) для jquery :-).

Если будут проблемы с реализацией кода перемещения наведённого элемента, пишите, помогу :-)

Comment: да, это описанного. если я не ошибаюсь, Вы предлагаете мне применить свойство `connectToSortable`. это немного не то. Мне нужно добавлять один элемент в сортируемый список. мне надо, что каждый элемент двигался и накладывался на своих соседей.

Comment: Не понимаю. Что именно вы хотите? Посмотрите пример по ссылке - я тащу элемент в список, и могу его переносить и он не накладывается на элемент, а класться рядом. Вам надо подобное, но не сверху вниз, а справа-слева ?

Может вам надо типа такого повидения?

http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/display-grid.html

Comment: @Чад, `connectToSortable` используется, когда надо перетаскиваемый элемент добавить в список и там он уже сортируется в зависимости от окружения. Мне надо сделать следующее: ширина родительского блока 1600px. три элемента в списке. мы берём элемент и тащим его. перенесли-отпустили, он остаётся на месте куда перенесли (`draggable`). Однако, если при перетаскивании элемента, он попадает на другой элемент, то уже необходимо поведение `sortable`(потому что перетаскиваемые элементы накладываются друг на друга), у которого элементы не накладываются друг на друга, а устанавливаются рядом.

Comment: Тогда я думая вам надо совместить draggable c dropable

Comment: @Чад, если бы всё так просто было!))))

Comment: @LeD4eG, так в чем проблема то?

Comment: @Чад, droppable() тоже не подходит - все элементы находятся в одной области. Приведу другой пример. Вы, я думаю, знаете, что такое слайдер. его ползунок перемещается в одной области по всей длине слайдера. Моя задача: сделать слайдер с 3 ползунками, чтобы при перемещении, ползунки не накладывались друг на друга, а оставались строго либо справа, либо слева. я думаю, это надо делать через позицию элемента ui. но дальше не могу придумать от чего оттолкнуться..

Comment: А свойство containment у draggable() разве не поможет ограничить переносы в одном контейнере? и ограничить перенос по одной из осей свойством axis ?